# Git clone failed with Gitlab and HTTPS (error 503 inside)

Tags: apache, https, gitlab

I have a Gitlab installation on a Kimsufi server installed from sources.
I use Apache and HTTPS with self-signed certificate.
Almost everything is working fine.

This is the problem :
I can't clone repository via HTTPS. Only SSH works fine.

> fatal: unable to access 'https://xxx/xxx/xxx.git/': The requested URL
>   returned error: 503

I think the problem comes from the Apache configuration (vhost).
Is there a log file somewhere or specific command I can run to debug this form client side or server side ?

Thx for help

Edit :

The request result with curl :

```
xxx@xxx:~/temp$ curl -v https://xxx.xxx.fr/xxx/xxx.git
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option
```

I think I have a certificate issue... Or CA ?